# Delay in loading multiple reports using report viewer in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am facing dramatic delay when loading SSRS reports in reportviewer dynamically in multiple popups. Once the first report is completely loaded, then only then next report starts processing even if I open the reports in parallel.
So I have to wait for long time to load small report if long running report is opened before it. Its not loading in parallel. 
I have done some research on this and got to know from the below link that ReportViewer blocks the session for loading each report.

http://www.networksteve.com/enterprise/topic.php/Multiple_report_viewers_on_one_page_issue/?TopicId=56213&Posts=5

Can anyone help me on this. Is there any solution available for this?

I am using Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms Version=11.0.0.0, and Framework 4.5 with VS 2012. ReportViewer is in server mode. Please see the code below

```
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ReportServer);
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = ReportPath.Trim();
reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
reportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: Do you experience the same issue when you run the reports directly from SSRS's Report Manager?  You can simulate the popups by shift-clicking to open a new window.

Comment: I don't get this delay when I run the reports directly from SSRS. Its opening in parallel. Popups are opened in new window only.

Comment: Are you setting the AsyncRendering property anywhere?  Maybe try toggling this value.  Also curious what kind of values you see in the SSRS logs --
`select * from ExecutionLog3`

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159110.aspx#bkmk_executionlog3

Comment: I have tried toggling AsyncRendering property but no luck. Will check the logs.

Comment: Also not sure what needs to be checked in logs. Its not giving any details for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe breaking up the processing into multiple threads could be the answer. Create a list of the reports you'll have to get, then use the `Parallel` class like so...

```
Parallel.ForEach(reports => report
{
    // code for rendering your report
});
```

Likewise, you can also create an `Action` delegate for each report and simplify this down to...

```
Parallel.ForEach(reports => report.Invoke());
```

Comment: I have tried treading. It does'nt make any difference in preformance. Also I am not loading all the reports together. On click of each link it will open each report in a new popup. But second one loads only after first one is completely loaded.

Comment: Have you looked at how the browser is handling the request? Here is an article that provides some initial background on that: http://www.technewsdaily.com/4519-slow-computer-web-browser-culprit.html